# Impala Daemon Not Starting in cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.10

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Impala not working in cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.10 as Impala Daemon is not starting.

Following is the status of the three required roles for Impala:

1. Impala Daemon is down
2. Impala Catalog Server has bad health &
3. Impala StateStore has good health

Getting following error messages:

```
Jul 22, 9:57:33.262 AM  ERROR   impala-server.cc:252    
Could not read the root directory at hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020. Error was: Call From quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1 to quickstart.cloudera:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Jul 22, 9:57:33.262 AM  ERROR   impala-server.cc:255    
Aborting Impala Server startup due to improper configuration. Impalad exiting.
```

Tried restarting the service through command line.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service impala-server restart
Stopped Impala Server:                                     [  OK  ]
Started Impala Server (impalad):                           [  OK  ]
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ service impala-server status
Impala Server is dead and pid file exists                  [FAILED]
```

Still it is not working.
Not sure if I can do some configuration changes for it or not. If so, could not find what exactly can be changed for it to work.

Comment: Hi, try the solutions from [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Hadoop-101-Training-Quickstart/Not-able-to-access-HDFS-getting-Connection-exception/td-p/28302) link.

Comment: I tried doing what is mentioned in the link, but this is not working for me. Impala Daemon is still not starting.